# how to check whether given List[Int] is sorted in scala?

Tags: scala

I would like to know whether is there any `isSorted()` function exist or not in scala.

Question: check whether `List[Int]` is sorted or not, If not remove smallest number and do again till `List[Int]` become sorted?

I want only 1 or 2 line program.

Answer (score 22):

You can compare each pair in the input sequence for lists containing more than 1 item:

```
def isSorted[T](s: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = s match {
    case Seq() => true
    case Seq(_) => true
    case _ => s.sliding(2).forall { case Seq(x, y) => ord.lteq(x, y) }
}
```

Comment: Writing `x < y` instead of `ord.lt` would be more clear :) And `<=` would be more correct as well.

Comment: should be ord.lteq(x, y), please edit your answer. I can't submit an edit because it's less than 6 characters

Comment: How could one write a two-parameter version, where the second parameter specifies whether to use `ord.lteq` or `ord.gteq` or some other method in [`scala.math.Ordering`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html)?

Answer (score 11):

It's not the best solution but you can use `sorted` method on list and then compare it with original one;

```
def sorted(l: List[Int]): Boolean = l == l.sorted
```

Answer (score 6):

With some lazyness:

```
def isSorted(l:List[Int]):Boolean = {
   val list = l.view
   !list.zip(list.tail).exists {case (x,y) => x>y}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Performing a sort just to check if the list is already sorted is a bit of an overkill. The optimal solution here seems to be the most obvious one, which is just describing the problem in human language and transferring it into code:

```
def isSorted[T](list: List[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = list match {
    case Nil => true // an empty list is sorted
    case x :: Nil => true // a single-element list is sorted
    case x :: xs => ord.lteq(x, xs.head) && isSorted(xs) // if the first two elements are ordered and the rest are sorted, the full list is sorted too
}
```

If you want it shorter, you could trade the 2nd case for a bit of readability:

```
def isSorted[T](list: List[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = list match {
    case Nil => true
    case x :: xs => xs.headOption.fold(true)(ord.lteq(x, _)) && isSorted(xs)
}
```

If you want a one-liner, that would be not readable at all:

```
def isSorted[T](list: List[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = list.headOption.fold(true)(a => list.tail.headOption.fold(true)(ord.lteq(a, _) && isSorted(list.tail.tail)))
```

Comment: A function that has two sets of brackets?! wtf? Nice answer though.

Answer (score 2):

def isSorted(xs: List[Int]): Boolean = (xs.tail zip xs).forall(pair => pair._1 - pair._2 > 0)

Comment: With questions this old (over 3 years), and so many existing answers (11), it's usually a good idea to include text explaining how your answer differs from all the others. In this case your answer looks very similar to the one from Nyavro, except that you chose to subtract-and-compare `pair._1 - pair._2 > 0` instead of a direct comparison `pair._1 > pair._2`.

Answer (score 2):

### Using `zip`

Lets do it **without actually sorting** the list.

Drop the head element in the intermediate list and then compare in pairs with original list. This way, `i`th element compares with `i+1`th element of the original list.

```
scala> val originalList = List(10, 20, 30, 40)
val originalList: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40)

scala> val intermediate = originalList.drop(1)
val intermediate: List[Int] = List(20, 30, 40)

scala> originalList.zip(intermediate)
val res5: List[(Int, Int)] = List((10,20), (20,30), (30,40))

scala> originalList.zip(intermediate).forall { case (orig, in) => orig <= in }
val res17: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

A inefficient but easy to understand answer:

```
def specialSort(a: List[Int]): List[Int] = 
  if (a == a.sorted) a 
  else specialSort(a.filterNot(_ == a.min))
```

Answer (score 1):

`l == l.sorted` didn't work for me, managed to do it with `l sameElements l.sorted`

Answer (score 0):

Here your one-line homework solution

```
def removeMinWhileNotSorted[A: Ordering](xs: List[A]): List[A] =  if (xs == xs.sorted) xs else xs.splitAt(xs.indexOf(xs.min))  match {case (prefix, m :: postfix) => removeMinWhileNotSorted(prefix ++ postfix)}
```

Comment: Upvoted for actually answering both bits of the question.

Comment: WARNING: match may not be exhaustive.
 It would fail on the following input: (_, Nil)

Comment: @actually Actually it will contain one guaranteed element (minimum). So you can ingnore the warning

Comment: Why write so much code in one line and without any explanations?

Comment: Yeah, why write so much code in one line and without any explanations?

Answer (score 0):

It does not exists. But it is easy to do: create a list with the joined version of the list and the same list sorted as you want and verify both elements of the joined list are the same.

Something like this:

```
import org.junit.Assert._

val sortedList = List(1, 3, 5, 7)
val unsortedList = List(10, 1, 8, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9)

// detailed test. It passes.
sortedList
  .zip(sortedList.sortWith((a,b) => a.compareTo(b) < 0)) // this is the required sorting criteria.
  .foreach(x => assertEquals("collection is not sorted", x._1, x._2))

// easier to read but similar test. It fails.
unsortedList
  .zip(unsortedList.sorted) // this is the required sorting criteria.
  .foreach(x => assertEquals("collection is not sorted", x._1, x._2))
```

a function could be:

```
def isSorted(list: List[Int]): Boolean = !list.zip(list.sortWith((a, b) => a.compareTo(b) < 0)).exists(p => !p._1.equals(p._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isSorted[T <% Ordered[T]](list: List[T]): Boolean =
    list.sliding(2).forall(p =>  (p.size==1) || p(0) < p(1))
```

Comment: you should provide an explanation why and how your code solves the problem, that would improve the quality a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that if two neighbor elements are equal it is legal too.

```
 def isSorted[T <% Ordered[T]](l: List[T]):Boolean ={
   val a = l.toArray
   (1 until a.length).forall(i => a(i-1) <= a(i))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (not necessarily any better than some of the other suggestions)

```
def isSorted[T <% Ordered[T]](a: List[T]): Boolean =
    if (a == Nil) true // an empty list is sorted
    else a.foldLeft((true, a.head))(
        (prev, v1) => {
            val (p, v0) = prev
        (p && v0 <= v1, v1)
    })._1
```

Results for a few test cases:

```
isSorted(Nil) -> true 
isSorted(1 :: Nil) -> true
isSorted(2 :: 3 :: Nil) -> true
isSorted(1 :: 2 :: 5 :: 8 :: Nil) -> true
isSorted(1 :: 1 :: 2 :: 2 :: Nil) -> true
isSorted(3 :: 2 :: Nil) -> false
isSorted(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 1 :: Nil) -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tail recursion to less create objects and to avoid stack overflow for long lists. This version is lazy, function return value instantly after a first unordered pair.

```scala
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def isSorted[T : Ordering](values: List[T]): Boolean = {
  import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

  values match {
    case fst :: snd :: _ if fst <= snd => isSorted(values.tail)
    case _   :: _   :: _               => false
    case _                             => true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```scala
def check(list: List[Int]) = {
  @tailrec
  def isSorted(list: List[Int], no: Int, acc: Boolean): Boolean = {
    if (list.tail == Nil) acc
    else if (list.head > no) {
      isSorted(list.tail, list.head, acc = true)
    }
    else isSorted(list.tail, list.head, acc=false)
  }
  isSorted(list, Integer.MIN_VALUE, acc = false)
}
```